# IF statement php displaying content if another is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have some fields (Wordpress) and sometimes one of them is empty. I want to display the content of 'the_excerpt' when the 'short_description' is not filled in.

here is what I came with:

```
    if (empty(the_field('short_description'))) {
      the_excerpt();
    } else {
      the_field('short_description'); 
    }
```

Unfortunately it displays both short_description and the except after that. What is wrong here? Do I miss something? For me the code looks good.

Comment: Use get_the_field, the_field prints the results immediately.

Comment: @TimSheehan 
you mean this?

if (empty(the_field('short_description'))) {
  the_excerpt();
} else {
  get_the_field('short_description'); 
}

it still displays both :(

Comment: No, he means that when you call `the_field('short_description')` it does not return the value, instead output is sent to the page directly,

Comment: Use get_the_field when checking your condition, use the_field when you want to print the result directly to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Check if value exists first use `get_field()` function instead of `the_field()`

Please have a look on example which shows how to check if a value exists before displaying it.

```
<?php if( get_field('short_description') ): ?>
    <?php the_field('short_description'); ?>
<?php else: ?>
   <?php  the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or you can user in another way like :

```
$isValue = get_field( "short_description" );
if( $isValue ) {
  echo $isValue ;
} else {
  the_excerpt();
}
```

Comment: thank you, I've used the first one. Works perfectly! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce: Show Custom Short Description When Empty

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'bbloomer_echo_short_desc_if_empty', 
21 );

 function bbloomer_echo_short_desc_if_empty() {
   global $post;
   if ( empty ( $post->post_excerpt  ) ) {
      $post_excerpt = '<p class="default-short-desc">';
      $post_excerpt .= 'This is the default, global, short description.<br>It will 
         show if <b>no short description has been entered!</b>';
      $post_excerpt .= '</p>';
     echo $post_excerpt;
   }
 }
```

This is a Right